# webkit-sharp for windows package

Tags: c#, windows, mono, webkit, gmcs

I wanted to try WebKit by following [this](http://huseyincakir.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/mono-webbrowser-with-webkit-gtk-not-winforms/) tutorial, but **gmcs** compiler was't able to find "webkit-sharp-1.0" package. Where can i get it and how to install it?

Answer (score 1):

The original Webkit# no longer seems under development (latest [commit](https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp/commits/master) is from 2009) and I have never encountered any windows packages for it but you can use [open-webkit-sharp](https://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/) which is working on Windows.

Comment: Open webkit sharp for .net is at https://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/
and many other links are available just google with open webkit sharp net